# Which book teaches the inner workings of how Xcode builds apps from code?

Tags: ios, xcode, clang, llvm, bytecode

I do iOS development and I'd like to have a deeper understanding of what is happening under the hood with Xcode.

Things like byte code, virtual machines, object files, bundles, executables, etc. And ideally, I'd like to know how all of these ideas tie into Xcode.

Which book should I get in order to learn this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this [objc.io](http://www.objc.io/issue-6/) series of articles about build tools.